# How to install Orbited on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, installation, orbited

I am trying to get Orbited working on OS X 10.6. Installing it in Linux was simple but I have seem to run into a roadblock. After installation when I try to run orbited server I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/opt/local/bin/orbited", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('orbited==0.7.10', 'console_scripts', 'orbited')()
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/orbited/start.py", line 114, in main
    install = _import('twisted.internet.%sreactor.install' % reactor_name)
  File "/opt/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/orbited/start.py", line 13, in _import
    return reduce(getattr, name.split('.')[1:], __import__(module_import))
ImportError: No module named kqueuereactor
```

I have twisted setup, Its the one that comes with OS X 10.6. Any solutions for this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Got it working with select for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the KQueue Reactor is not being maintained for OSX and its a Mac issue so select is the way to go for now.

Please let me know if there is a better solution